# Document root change help

Tags: security, .htaccess, security-scan-tool

I am using Magento 2.3.1 Open Source.  I installed it from the .zip file in the public_html folder (I didn't know any better at the time) in my account at my web host, running on Apache.

I did the Magento Security Scan on my website, and it showed the following problem-

```
Your Web server is configured to run Magento from %MAGENTO_ROOT% directory. 

It is recommended to set %MAGENTO_ROOT%/pub as a Web server root directory.
```

In response I found my way to this page

> **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html**

which had instructions to fix the problem, but they seem to only apply to installations 
that are not on shared web hosting plans.

I tried to find the files that contain the document root url through SSH-ing into the shared server just in case, but since I don't have root access it didn't show.

I contacted my hosting provider twice to change the document root for me through **`/var/cpanel/userdata/username/example.com`**, but since there is a language barrier, they told me that that was beyond their expertise, or something like that.

My site is run under https, of course, if that helps any.

I am not too security savvy with Magento, so what I want to know is, if I use the **.htaccess** commands below to change the document root, would they alone make my Magento installation in public_html secure?-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pub/$1 [L]
```

**Do I need to move/copy any Magento files from public_html to public_html/pub if I use the *.htaccess* commmands above, if so, which files?**

If I leave the Magento files in public_html and use the rewrite commands, will that be a security problem?

Do I need to change any settings in the Magento Admin after using the rewrite commands?

Thank you very much.

Comment: no need to move any files, if your root is `/pub/` and you have working site its ok, magento can work from two web roots

Comment: Thanks for verifying that I don't need to move my files around. Do you know of any security problems that may arise if I do any of the other things like I spoke of above?

Comment: correct way is to configure `DocumentRoot` to avoid any issues with rewrites.

Comment: any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your host you may be able to sort yourself.

Do you have a cpanel login?

Check this demo

https://demo.cpanel.net:2083/cpsess6663391586/frontend/paper_lantern/index.html?login=1&post_login=30734131148808

Under domains you may have the option to change your document root to `/public_html/pub/`

You do not need to modify any Magento files.  If you have modified any files undo your changes first.

Extract the site as normal under `public_html`

In terms of security the site will be in the same state. That said the point in all this is to avoid visitors being able to access folders to trigger a setup wizard or browse for other vulnerabilities. Providing you lock folders down via htaccess and maintain these then your site is secure. The idea is that one folder /pub is easier to keep safe than many app/etc bin etc

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: Just quick note - last time I tried this on a cpanel server I couldn't get the setup screens to load.  So you may have to install Magento first and then alter doc root after

Comment: Thanks for verifying that I don't need to modify any files.  Yes, I have a cPanel login, and I was not able to do it through that.  I also attempted to change the document root through SSH, but since I did not have filesystem root access, I could not.  Do you know of any security problems if I do things like I spoke of above?

Comment: In terms of security the site will be in the same state. That said the point in all this is to avoid visitors being able to access folders to trigger a setup wizard or browse for other vulnerabilities. Providing you lock folders down via htaccess and maintain these then your site is secure.  The idea is that one folder `/pub` is easier to keep safe than many `app/etc` `bin` etc

Comment: If you care to, modify your answer by putting your comment just above into it, and possibly add a link to information about Rewrites and security (if there is one), and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sure. All done.

Answer (score 0):

In case others want to know how to do this, this is what I did, and where I put the code to make the document root change work.

I edited the .htaccess file inside of my public_html folder, and placed the needed code under this section / heading:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/
```

This is the code that needs to go in that section for a simple rewrite.  Be sure to change "example" to your domain name, that is, if your domain name is bluecar.com, you would replace "example" below with bluecar:

```
RewriteBase /public_html/pub

# Rewrites all URLS without pub in them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/

# Rewrites all URLS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pub/$1 [L]
```

That code worked for my site to direct web browsers to the /pub folder.

I'm not very savvy with .htaccess commands, so make any needed backups if you use this code.

After I made the changes, I ran the Magento Security Scan again, and again it showed the same error.  This was expected seeing how it looks for the  document root line in certain files I can't get to.

But, to make sure that my .htaccess changes were indeed working (calling /pub/index.php), I edited the index.php file in the /pub folder to have it write a line of text to a file, and it did.

From all of the research that I did, this appears to be a secure approach.

All of the tests that I have done on my site since this change are positive.

I hope this helps others.

If I have made any errors / mistakes, or overlooked a security issue, please someone point them out.